# what is supposed to be the return of getTermset in pnp/sp-taxonomy

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, taxonomy, term-store, term-set

I am using pnp sp to retrieve the termset, i am using this:

```
const store: any = await taxonomy.termStores.getByName("Taxonomy_9D1X5aueEcT7a3LKqetQKw==");
        const sets: ITermSets = taxonomy.termStores.getByName("termstore name")
                .getTermSetsByName("Division", 1033);
        console.log(sets);

        return sets;
```

i have also tried this, from the [documentation](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp-taxonomy/docs/term-stores/):

```
// note that you can also use instances if you wanted to conduct multiple operations on a single store
const store: ITermStore = taxonomy.termStores.getByName("Taxonomy_v5o/SbcTE2cegwO2dtAN9l==");
const set: ITermSet = store.getTermSetById("0ba6845c-1468-4ec5-a5a8-718f1fb05431");
```

but i dont see anything that i can use from the returned value?

[image]

i need to retrieve the values from this Term Set: (Division)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp-taxonomy/docs/term-sets/) there's an example:

```
import { taxonomy, ITermStore, ITermSet } from "@pnp/sp-taxonomy";

const store: ITermStore = taxonomy.termStores.getByName("Taxonomy_v5o/SbcTE2cegwO2dtAN9l==");

const set = store.getTermSetsByName("my set", 1031).getById("0ba6845c-1468-4ec5-a5a8-718f1fb05431");

const setWithData = store.getTermSetsByName("my set", 1031).getByName("my set").get();
```

Notice the extra `.getByName("my set").get();` after the `getTermSetsByName` call.
So, I assume in your case you should add add an extra **`get()`** call.

Haven't tested it though.